# What is $S^2 \times S^2$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

What does the product of these spaces mean? 
I really cannot understand or wrap my head around it.
What is it done for?

If someone could help in visualizing it or provide intuition, it would be great.

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky Isn't a circle usually denoted by $S^1$?

Comment: What does the product of two topological spaces mean? This is just the definition of $X \times Y$. For an intuition, really $S^1\times S^1$ is better.

Comment: Do you know the definition of the Cartesian product of two topological spaces?

Comment: @LeeMosher have brief idea of it.

Comment: Is your question about the general meaning of the Cartesian product? Or something more special about this particular Cartesian product $S^2 \times S^2$?

Comment: @LeeMosher it is limited to S^2 X S^2

Comment: A point in this product space is two spheres with a point selected in each. Every distinct pair of points on the two spheres is a different point in the product space.

Comment: Alternatively, you can visualize the space of ordered pairs of points on $S^2$.

Comment: A suggestion: open your topology textbook and read the actual definition of the product topology. Then read the definition of the subspace topology. Then try to prove why the product topology on the product of two 2-spheres is naturally homeomorphic to the subspace topology if you embed the product of these spheres in$R^6$. Let us know if you can do this exercise.

Answer (score 2):

As @Lee Mosher pointed out, the definition of the cartesian product,

$$ X \times Y = \{(x,y): x \in X, y \in Y\}$$

Well, since we are doing topology, a more geometric definition would be beneficial. Hence, you can think of the product in two following ways,

1) At each point $x$, there is a copy of $Y$

2) At each point $y$, there is a copy of $X$

Why does this help? Well think of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. If we think of this as joining $ \cup_x\{x\} \times \mathbb{R}$ in the plane, then we see a bunch of copies of lines i.e the plane is built from lines either in the horizontal or vertical direction. This is where you can see the idea of fibers/bundles extending from. The plane is therefore realized as a line bundle over $\mathbb{R}$ with fibers $X$ or $Y$, depending on how you choose to look at things.

$\textbf{Addition}$: Also, cartesian products of manifolds is the most straightforward way of getting a new manifold. You have to think a bit when it comes to getting new manifolds via quotients e.g $\mathbb{R}/ \mathbb{Z} \cong S^1$. Old manifold $\mathbb{R}$ and we get the new one $S^1$ by defining an equivalence relation.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Product spaces are very easy to understand. They are spaces consisting of multiple other spaces, in each of which you may choose a point.

For instance, in this example, we have two spheres $S^2$. A point in this product space is a selection of a point on each sphere.

For an intuition: maybe we want to plant a flag on Mars and the Moon. Where on the surfaces shall we plant these flags? We have two spheres, on each of which we may choose a point on the surface. This space of choices is $S^2 \times S^2$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My advisor would draw a rectangle on the blackboard and label it $E$, a horizontal line parallel to the bottom edge and label it $M$, and say, "Let $p:E \to M$ be a principal bundle."

In that spirit (but embellished for illustration), $S^{2} \times S^{2}$ looks like this:

[image: The Cartesian product of two $2$-spheres]

Each horizontal line in the grid represents a $2$-sphere that projects to a single point of the left-hand sphere. Each vertical line represents a $2$-sphere that projects to a point of the bottom sphere.

If you stare long enough (perhaps over a period of months or years) at diagrams of this type, you develop a degree of "geometric intuition" that may include being able to see (in roughly increasing order of familiarity):

- How two of the $2$-spheres described above are either disjoint or intersect in one point;
- How ordinary flat $2$-tori are contained in the product;
- How $S^{2} \times S^{2}$ is obtained from the Cartesian product of two $2$-disks (whose boundary comprises two solid tori intersecting along a $2$-torus "corner") by pinching the corner to a single point while "zipping up" each solid torus by collapsing its circle factor;
- How to obtain this closed $4$-manifold from the complex projective plane through birational transformations (blowing up two points $p$ and $q$, then blowing down the proper transform of the line through $p$ and $q$);

and so forth.

Comment: **Each horizontal line in the grid represents a $2$-sphere that projects to a single point of the left-hand sphere** - shouldn't each $2$-sphere project to a 2D sphere, not a 1D line? Not only does this visualisation miss out on the topology (going to a flat plane instead of a closed surface), but it also shows a space of only 2 dimensions instead of 4! Is there something I'm not understanding?

Comment: @Myridium: That's why I said **represents** rather than **is**. The square grid is explicitly representational (or if you prefer, metaphorical), not literal, but contains enough conceptual scaffolding to reconstruct $S^{2} \times S^{2}$ (or an arbitrary product of topological spaces). One point is, it's not necessary--or even desirable--to be too literal. (I was initially inclined to put a horizontal segment below and a vertical segment to the left of the square, but weakened, putting in spheres instead.)